# How to replace substring in DataFrame column by variable pattern in Julia?

Tags: replace, julia

Suppose I have a DataFrame with two columns - `gibberish` and `letter`.
I want to replace substrings in `gibberish` so that only the ones matching `letter` remain, e.g. If `gibberish` is `"kjkkj"` and the `letter` is `"j"` I want `gibberish` to equal `"jj"`.

The DataFrame is defined as:

```
df = DataFrame(gibberish = ["dqzzzjbzz", "jjjvjmjjkjjjjjjj", "mmbmmlvmbmmgmmf"], letter = ["z", "j", "m"])
```

If I had no `letter` variable and wanted only, let's say "x" to remain I would do:

```
df.gibberish.= replace.(gibberish, r"[^x;]" => "")
```

and that works fine, but when I try doing the same, but putting in `letter` column as a variable in the regex expression, it just breaks.
I tried doing that the "normal" DataFrames.jl way and with DataFramesMeta.jl shortcut `@transform`:

```
df.gibberish.= replace.(gibberish, Regex(join(["[^", letter, ";]"])) => "")
```

which results in an error of

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: letter not defined
```

while the `@transform` way just doesn't do anything:

```
julia> @transform(df, filtered = replace(:gibberish, Regex.(join(["[^", :letter, ";]"])) => ""))
3×3 DataFrame
│ Row  │ letter │ gibberish         │ filtered          │
│      │ String │ String            │ String            │
├──────┼────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ 1    │ z      │ dqzzzjbzz         │ dqzzzjbzz         │
│ 2    │ j      │ jjjvjmjjkjjjjjjj  │ jjjvjmjjkjjjjjjj  │
│ 3    │ m      │ mmbmmlvmbmmgmmf   │ mmbmmlvmbmmgmmf   │
```

I'm a very fresh beginner in Julia and I'm probably missing something very basic, but the proper solution just escapes me.
How do I solve this problem, other than writing a rowwise loop which would be horribly inefficient?

Comment: Provide a more complete, reproducible code to get higher quality help.  For example your question doesn't show what you defined `letter` to be - is it defined anywhere?

Comment: I added bit of code of how it is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
replace.(gibberish, Regex(join(["[^", letter, ";]"]))
```

letter refers here to a Julia variable (which is not defined), not to a column of the DataFrame.

You could try something like

```
Regex.(string.("[^" .* df.letter .* ";]"))
```

to construct an array of Regexes using a DataFrame row as input.

Comment: I tried to do `df.filtered = replace.(df.gibberish, Regex.(string.("[^" .* gibberish.letter .* ";]")) => "")` but got an error `ERROR: MethodError: no method matching findnext(::Array{Regex,1}, ::String, ::Int64)`

Comment: maybe add a dot before => ?